How do I get Git to stop ignoring a real folder that's called Release?
I'm aware that this appears to be a duplication of the question at Git to ignore Release folders but include the specific Libraries\Release folder , but the solution there isn't working for me, and I'm concerned that something has changed since it was asked and answered 5 years ago.
I have a View called \Views\Release\Index.cshtml. So I went to the .gitignore file, where it was excluding [Rr]elease and [Rr]eleases, and added a line after that to un-ignore this folder and the views in it:
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
!/Views/Release
x64/
x86/

I closed Visual Studio (I'm using VS2022) and reopened it, in case that was necessary in order for VS to look at the files with a fresh eye, and even rebuilt the solution. And this is what displays in Solution Explorer.

I know I have the option of renaming the folder and changing all the links, but I'd rather not. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Just explicitly add the desired file to your repo. An added file doesn't care about the ignore file.

Only trust Git using git status to check the immediate effect of your .gitignore configuration.
Your .gitignore properly works:
mkdir test-gitiginore
cd test-gitiginore
git init
mkdir -p Views/Release
touch Views/Release/Index.cshtml
git status -u  # Views/Release/Index.cshtml is ignored.

On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    Views/Release/Index.cshtml

cat <<"EOF > .gitignore
# Build results
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
!/Views/Release
x64/
x86/
EOF
git status -u  # Views/Release/Index.cshtml is no more ignored.

On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    .gitignore
    Views/Release/Index.cshtml

The problem comes from your IDE that does not properly adapt to your .gitignore file.
Maybe there is a manual "update" action (or something like this) to make your IDE read again the file.
